# В театре чужой успех зачастую воспринимают(,) как собственное поражение

Tags: синтаксис

В театре чужой успех зачастую воспринимают как собственное поражение.
Почему в данном примере не ставится запятая перед как?
Ведь здесь же можно как заменить на будто!
Или же здесь "как" имеет значение "в качестве" ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Ответ исправлен (с учетом критики)

**Воспринимают как собственное поражение** - здесь оборот  **тесно связан со сказуемым по смыслу.**

**Общее правило:**

Оборот с союзом КАК (со значением тождества, а не сравнения) не обособляется, если тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым в основном сообщении.В этом случае оборот имеет значение «В КАЧЕСТВЕ», «СЧИТАЯ», «РАССМАТРИВАЯ».

**Примеры:**

1) Значение  «считая»:    Все относились к нему как к чудаку.

2) Значение  «рассматривая»: Смотрите на меня как на пациента.

3) Значение  «в качестве»:  Мы знаем Индию как страну древнейшей культуры. 
Я говорю как литератор. Любое внимание к своему творчеству он воспринимал как похвалу.

Comment: *Оборот не обособляется, если он является сказуемым* - ну и формулировочки у вас, однако... Зачем велосипед изобретать, если есть понятные и известные?

Comment: А вообще такое впечатление, что вы не на тот подпункт правила ссылаетесь.  Если оборот "является"  сказуемым, то это пункт *"4. Если союз КАК стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым (без этого союза там требовалось бы поставить тире), например: Озеро как зеркало;"* (http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183; у Розенталя близкие формулировки), у нас это условие не выполняется. Разницу между вашими 2) и 3) вообще не понял.

Comment: Извините, примеры относились к сравнительному обороту, а в приведенном примере нет сравнения.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет сравнительного оборота вовсе. *"Как поражение"* входит в состав сказуемого и без него предложение было бы грамматически неполно. Такие случаи, естественно, не обособляются.

> 3. Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла, например: *Она держится как хозяйка;*

http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183

Что же вашего предложения проверить заменой на "как будто", то это прием (пунктограмма) не имеет абсолютной силы, здесь и после замены на "как будто" запятой не требуется. 
Чтобы воспользоваться приемом наверняка, необходимо, чтобы 
оборот с как относился непосредственно к слову, которому идет уподобление.

*В театре чужой успех, как собственное поражение, воспринимается болезненно.* 
Вот тут есть прямое сопоставление успеха и поражения, поэтому проверка обособления заменой "как" на "как будто" вполне правомерна. В нашем же случае мешает слово "воспринимается", к которому и относится "как...".

Comment: Скажите,а в вашем коментарии "Такие случаи, естественно, не обособляются " - естественно водное слово ?

Comment: @KirikPul - В моем - да, значение близкое по значению к "конечно", "очевидно" и проч. Да тут по-другому и не прочитаешь. Иное возможно только в составе сказуемого: "Это было естественно и непринужденно" - вот тут точно не вводное.

Answer (score 0):

Свой успех поражением никак и никем не понимается и не воспринимается. Напротив, чужая победа всегда является собственным проигрышем, и здесь они — победа и проигрыш (успех и поражение) — равнозначны. Тождественное запятой в приведённой фразе обособлять не следует.